# How to change some text in a file by StreamWriter

Tags: c#, winforms, filestream

I'm trying to change some text in a .CSV file.

```
StreamReader sReader = new StreamReader(path1);
while (sReader.Peek() != -1)
{
    rowValue = sReader.ReadLine();
    if (rowValue == "25")
    {
         sWriter = new StreamWriter(path1);
         rowValue = "27";
         sWriter.WriteLine(rowValue);
    }
}
```

Nothing happened. What is the correct way, please?

Comment: Your not actually writing anything to the stream, your just creating a new instance of a `StreamWriter` and changing `rowValue`'s value.

Comment: I added a line to write rowValue. Again, the row is "25"

Comment: @ yogi, I don't know anything about Flush().

Comment: @Alice - Is it really a CSV type file?  Or just plain text with a single value on each line?

Comment: @ Chris, the file has extension .csv and each value in each line is separated by comma

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily accomplish this task with System.IO.File.ReadAllLines and System.IO.File.WriteAllLines

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(path1);

for(int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
{
  if(lines[i] == "25") lines[i] = "27";
}

File.WriteAllLines(path1, lines);
```

Comment: Corrected the syntax issues... typing too fast, but gots to on this site.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe you can do what you're trying to do ... updating a single line. If it's working at all, you're appending the value `27` to the end of your file.

Check out the [`ReadAllLines`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2tte0y1.aspx) and [`WriteAllLines`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/92e05ft3.aspx) methods. You need to read the entire file in, change the line(s) you want to change, then write it back.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if the file to read is not a very big one, you could try to read everything in memory and write back

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(path1);
using(StreamWrite sw = new StreamWriter(path1))
{
    foreach(string line in lines)
    {
        string lineOut = line;
        if (line == "25") 
           lineOut = "27"; 
        sw.WriteLine(lineOut);
    }
    sw.Flush();
}
```

Comment: Steve, I have an error on line 7 - Cannot assign to 'line' because it is a 'foreach iteration variable

Comment: @Alice, answer updated,but consider also the alternative presented by Chris Gessler. It's more direct

Comment: Yess ! Solved. ThankYou, Steve and Chris